# how to make QLabel auto-linefeed?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is the similar question: "[QLabel auto multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281396/qlabel-auto-)
multiple-lines"

You can see the privious question in the end of this question. Now the question turn to how can I adjust the width of the label in the following picture?
[image]

-------------------------------- the previous question --------------------------------

I did use the "labelName->setWordWrap(true);"

While the question I come across is in the following picture:
[image]

From above, we cannot see the two lines clearly. How should I deal with it?
Comment: It's calling adjustSize() "after" setting the text that works!

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase height of your `QLabel`. You could do this automatically by calling `adjustSize()` member function after setting the text. Proper layout setting should also help.

In order to set minimum width of your widget you need to call, well, `setMinimumWidth`:

```
labelName->setMinimumWidth(width);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's calling adjustSize() "after" setting the text that works!