# Converting QString from string in a file

Tags: c++, qt

I want to set a text in a `QLabel` so I need to use a `QString`.
But I read a file and the text contains accents.
I tried with `QString::fromUtf8()` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

```
string line;
QString lineTranslate;
getline(file, line);
lineTranslate = QString::fromStdString(line);
m_nomCourant->setText(QString::fromLatin1("<u><strong>Nom courant :</strong></u> ") + lineTranslate);
```

Desired output:

```
Nom courant : Requin
Nom scientifique : Carcharhinus menalopterus

Habitat : Côtier / Dans les zones coralliennes jusqu'à -30m
Famille : Carcharhinidés
```

Actual output:

```
Nom courant : Requin
Nom scientifique : Carcharhinus menalopterus

Habitat : C?tier / Dans les zones coralliennes jusqu'? -30m
Famille : Carcharhinid?s
```

Edit: What do you advise me to use to have a `QString` with several lines?

Comment: Could you include your desired and actual output in your question?

Comment: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/858012Capture.png

Comment: If you want several lines and are using html, just use <br/>

Comment: Thx Morb. But it will better if it is automatic (when the QString is too long for the QLabel for exemple).

Comment: I think this question can help you with this other problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281396/qlabel-auto-multiple-lines

Comment: Yes ! It works with this way. Thx Morb. Now my first question ? haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know what encoding (charset) is used in your file. Then you will either use `fromUtf8`, or something else - using the `QTextCodec`.

Example from Qt docs:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Shift-JIS");
QTextDecoder *decoder = codec->makeDecoder();

QString string;
while (new_data_available()) {
    QByteArray chunk = get_new_data();
    string += decoder->toUnicode(chunk);
}
delete decoder;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I didn't think to that. So I changed the encoding of my file to Utf8. And it works with my last code. Thx Googie.