# How to break QLabel text on multiple lines?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5

Please, I have a problem with my UI. As shown in the image below:[image]

I just want to limit the `QLabel` width so the text boxes are aligned together.

I'm sorry that my question may be vague, and doesn't have a minimal code because it's `ui` file. If you want more information, let me know in the comments.

P.S. I set the `wordWrap` to `true` according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281629/6941952).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `horizontal stretch` was set to `0` for all 3 neighbors widgets. As a result, they were expanding. Now, it's set to `1`, so the window width is divided equally between the 3 widgets.