# Auto line break with QLabel inside QTableWidget

Tags: qt, word-wrap, line-breaks

I'm working on a `QTableWidget` with some `QLabel` inside it, but I need the QLabel to line-break automatically. I've tried `setWordWrap` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281396/qlabel-auto-multiple-lines):

```
QVBoxLayout *newL = new QVBoxLayout;
QTableWidget * tab = new QTableWidget; tab->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
newL->addWidget(tab);

tab->setRowCount(1);
tab->setColumnCount(1);

QLabel *lb = new QLabel; lb->setText("testing");
lb->setWordWrap(true);
tab->setCellWidget(0,0,lb);

QWidget *window = new QWidget;
window->setLayout(newL);
window->show();
```

### Problems

1. If one word is really lengthy, the `wordWrap` doesn't move to a new line. Instead, it just expand into outer region:

```
lb->setText("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestawd");
```

[image: first]

2. If there're multiple lines (more than 2), the `QTableWidget` doesn't create more lines, so the lower lines are not shown:

```
lb->setText("test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest");
```

[image: sec]

3. Even if there're only spaces between words, the `QTableWidget` still doesn't expand more than 2 lines:

```
lb->setText("test              test        test       test           test        test       test");
```

[image: third]

### Questions

1. For the first problem, I'd like the text to switch to new line exactly at the point that the text go to outer region, **even if** there're no `\n` character.
2. For the second and third problem, I'd like the `QWidgetTable` to provide enough space to show all the text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Qt `wordWrap` documentation: [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop)

If this property is true then label text is wrapped where necessary **at word-breaks**; otherwise it is **not wrapped at all**.